# How to run useQuery inside forEach?

Tags: javascript, graphql, hook, apollo

I have loop - forEach - which find productId for every element of array. I want to fetch my database by productId using apollo query. 
How to do it?

```
products.forEach(({ productId, quantity }) =>
    // fetch by 'productId'

);
```

Comment: Note that this potentially points to a bigger issue with your API. If you're getting the list of products from the API already, you should be able to just request the product details in that query and not have to make a separate, additional query for each product.

Comment: My app is microservice with different databases. And I think this is problem

Comment: I have services:
api-gateway
classifieds-app

carts-service
orders-service
products-service
users-service

And this 4 services above has different databases. And this is reason to make separate, additional query for each product. But I don't know how to deal with it.

Anyway, thank you for response. This really help me! Best wishes!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [the rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level):

> **Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.** Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders.

Hooks cannot be used inside a loop, so you can't use them inside a `forEach` callback.

You should create a separate component for each product that only uses the `useQuery` hook once. You can then `map` over the products and return the component for each one:

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  ...
  return products.map(({ productId, quantity }) => (
    <Product key={productId} productId={productId} quantity={quantity} />
  ))
}

const Product = () => {
  const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(...)
  // render your data accordingly
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I have question ;) 
"Separate component" what this can look like? I don't have idea

Comment: Updated question with expanded example

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck with the same problem, you helped me a lot

Comment: This doesn't solve problem, when query needs to be ran to fetch dynamic amount of items, but data can't be split into individual components.

Comment: What if I need all the product details in the same component?

Comment: Thats one of hook drawbacks - you need to create NEW component just to be able run a hook in a loop... :(

Answer (score 8):

If you want to perform multiple calls to `useQuery` then you can't do that in a forEach, map etc. You need to use `useQueries` e.g.

```
function Products({ productIds }) {
  const productQueries = useQueries({
    queries: productIds.map(productId => {
      return {
        queryKey: ['productById', productId],
        queryFn: () => fetchProductById(productId),
      }
    })
  })
```

Example taken from: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/parallel-queries

Answer (score 1):

To run useQuery based on logic or manually **multiple** times by setting **refetchOnWindowFocus** & **enable** properties to false and then calling method **refetch()**. example as below.

```
const RefetchExample = () => {

const manualFetch = {
  refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
  enabled: false
}

const GetAssetImage = async () => {
  const {data} = await axiosInstance.get("Your API")
  return data
}

const {assetImage, refetch} = useQuery('assetImage', GetAssetImage, manualFetch)

const imageFetch = () => {
    refetch();
}
return (
   <Button onClick={imageFetch}>Refetch</Button>
)
}

export default RefetchExample
```

Comment: refetch() - doesnt accept a query value to fetch data on dynamic IDs for example. So this unswer doesnt apply for this question. since he needs to fetch data based on different IDs in each loop.